# How can i limit polar grid in gnuplot?

Tags: grid, gnuplot

My data is in polar coordinates and when i plot them and try to add the polar grid it will be complete circles but my data is only from 0-60 degrees.

How can i limit the grid only from 0-60 degrees only, and not a complete circle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of a built-in feature for this. However, as a workaround, one might use the `multiplot` in order to draw the grid lines manually.
For example:

```
set term pngcairo enhanced size 800,800
set output 'fig.png'

set angles degrees

set multiplot

set lmargin at screen 0.1
set tmargin at screen 0.9
set rmargin at screen 0.9
set bmargin at screen 0.1

set samples 1000
unset border

R_max = 1
dR = 0.2

phi_max = 60.
dphi = 15

set xr [0:R_max]
set yr [0:R_max]

set xtics out nomirror
unset ytics

set style line 42 lc rgb '#666666' dt 3

unset key
plot \
    for [i=0:phi_max/dphi] (x>=0&&x<=R_max*cos(i*dphi))?tan(i*dphi)*x:1/0 w l ls 42

set polar
set trange [0:phi_max]
unset raxis
unset rtics
plot \
    for [i=1:ceil(R_max/dR)] i*dR<=R_max?i*dR:1/0 w l ls 42

unset raxis
unset rtics
plot cos(t) w l lw 2 lc rgb 'dark-red'
```

produces:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped a lot.
i have one more question if possible.




I am using this code to plot heatmap data with the grid, and it works perfectly as in the link
but it dosent fill the area, and if i use dgrid3d it will give me a square.
i had to transform my data from polar to Cartesian in order to use splot
in this link you will find the two graphs and the code i am using
https://mega.nz/#F!hcQEHbqR!NVxeSrFoy1-YcEbItzwnng
sample of data
0.0498099 0.00435558 -568.242889
0.0996199 0.00871117 -569.395867
0.14943 0.0130668 -570.975623
0.19924 0.0174223 -572.153443